# LaTeX semantic checker

Tags: tex-core

I used to write papers in math on LaTex. I wounder if there exists some program which makes semantic check. 
I want that there will check for example that it will warn on grammar mistakes, and will know to handle latex. Warn for example if I open ( but not close it.
Check for math common mistakes like +\ldots+ ussually should be +\cdots+.

Comment: For what semantic shall such a tool check? I think you just mean a syntax check, which is more or less done by the Latex compiler itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [ChkTeX](http://www.nongnu.org/chktex/) and [lacheck](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/lacheck/) which are both included in TeX Live.  IMHO ChkTeX is superior, but I recently became it's maintainer, so I'm biased.  There may be others as well that I don't know about.  If there is something that it doesn't check that you would like, feel free to leave a feature request on the [bug tracker](https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?group=chktex).

ChkTeX is certainly not a full grammar checker since such a thing is quite hard, and extremely language dependent.  But it catches common LaTeX mistakes, but I think that's what you want.